# When is java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer thrown with Netty?

Tags: java, socket.io, netty, serversocket

When I send a request to a webserver using netty. I get the following exception. What can cause this exception ?

```
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
        at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledHeapByteBuf.setBytes(UnpooledHeapByteBuf.java:237) ~[netty-all-4.0.6.Final.jar:na]
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:867) ~[netty-all-4.0.6.Final.jar:na]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:227) ~[netty-all-4.0.6.Final.jar:na]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:87) ~[netty-all-4.0.6.Final.jar:na]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:497) ~[netty-all-4.0.6.Final.jar:na]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:465) ~[netty-all-4.0.6.Final.jar:na]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:359) ~[netty-all-4.0.6.Final.jar:na]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:101) ~[netty-all-4.0.6.Final.jar:na]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
```

Answer (score 5):

The usual cause of this error is that you have written to a connection which had already been closed by the other end. In other words, an application protocol error. There are other causes, but this is the most common.

NB Netty has nothing to do with it.

Comment: How would you handle/recover from this? Currently having this issue using  Lettuce to connect to a Redis server.

Answer (score -2):

Try check and catch exception before read. It helped me rid of that exception.

```
// Attempt to read off the channel
        int numRead;
        try {
            numRead = socketChannel.read(this.readBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // The remote forcibly closed the connection, cancel
            // the selection key and close the channel.
            key.cancel();
            socketChannel.close();
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question ('why?'); it didn't 'rid [you] of that exception', it just caught it in a different place; and cancelling the key before closing the channel is redundant.